# Can I install SQL Server Management Studio on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: server, mssql

Can I install SQL Server Management Studio on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-install-Microsoft-SQL-management-studio-in-Ubuntu-If-yes-how

Comment: Microsoft now pushes [Azure Data Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017) with a Linux download link on this page. Previously released under the preview name SQL Operations Studio, Azure Data Studio offers a modern editor experience with IntelliSense, code snippets, source control integration, and an integrated terminal. It is engineered with the data platform user in mind, with built in charting of query result sets and customizable dashboards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. You can use [SQL Server Management Studio on Windows to manage SQL Server on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-manage-ssms?view=sql-server-linux-2017) but the software itself needs Windows. The link from Microsoft does have a tip about a new tool that can:

> **Tip**
>
> If you do not have a Windows machine to run SSMS on, consider the new [SQL Server Operations Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/index?view=sql-server-linux-2017). It provides a graphical tool for managing SQL Server and runs on both Linux and Windows.

[SQL Server Operations Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/download?view=sql-server-linux-2017) is currently only available as a preview but does have a download to a [DEB installer](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=875607).

Installation after downloading the deb:

```
cd ~
sudo dpkg -i ./Downloads/sqlops-linux-<version string>.deb    
sqlops
```

Comment: Now it is called Azure Data Studio

Comment: link to Azure Data Studio : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio

Answer (score 6):

You can use Visual Studio Code (from Linux, Windows, Mac) to [connect to SQL Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql).

[Here is a tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-vscode) how to connect to SQL Server on Azure.

Comment: this is great idea, noting to install just use VSSCode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Beekeeper Studio to manage multiple SQL databases.
[Beekeeper Studio](https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/)

Comment: This works but has very limited features as compared to the SSMS.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft renamed SQL Server Operations Studio to Azure Data Studio. You can read about it and download it on this Microsoft official website:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15